# Sliding a padded activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-animation, android-styles

[image: This is my screenshot]I have a padded activity over another activity.I want an animation to slide the padded activity to the left(`slide_out_left` animation).But the problem is,since i have padded the activity the normal `slide_out_left` animation shown below does not work properly.What changes i need to make to the normal `slide_out_left` animation code?

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-50%p"
           android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
<alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
       android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
```

Comment: "does not work properly" -> can you be more specific on what the issue is ?

Comment: i mean that i dont get a clean slide out left animation,its because the animation is from 0% to -50%,but since i have padded my activity these values dont work...